# Getting access error when using NodeJS to download shared file from Google Drive

Tags: node.js, google-api

I'm trying to build a node js app that uses the googleapis npm package and watches a shared google drive folder and automatically downloads new or modified files.  I can access the folder and see the files, but when I try downloading, I get this response (appid and fileid redacted):

```
 errors:
   [ { domain: 'global',
       reason: 'appNotAuthorizedToFile',
       message: 'The user has not granted the app read access to the file .',
       locationType: 'header',
       location: 'Authorization' } ] }
```

I've authorized my app on the Google Drive API (which is why it can successfully see the files), but I can't figure out what I need to do to give it the permission to download these publicly shared files.  I've poured over the docs on the Google API site, but still couldn't figure it out.  I'd like to avoid using a file picker, as I'm hoping to make the process automatic: It sees a new/modified file, and it downloads it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: When the file is shared as "On - Anyone with the link" by the owner, other users can download the file using the file ID by Drive API. If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately, I tried adjusting the settings to both "On - Anyone with the link" and then also to the publicly shared with no sign in required one.  Neither worked, and the app continued to give me the same error as above.

I've verified that my oauth token seems to be correct and is getting passed in with the call to download the file.

Comment: Can I ask you about the type and size of the shared file you want to download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that your client app is using the wrong [scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/about-auth) that only allows you to view file metadata. Therefore you're only allowed to list files but cannot download them.

Try changing the scope to something that allows you to read file contents (e.g. `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly`). You can follow the [Node.js quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs) example and see how scopes are handled there.

Keep in mind when you change the scope, you need to get a new access token as well.

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly what the problem was.